# Fixing gap on wall

Tags: walls

I built a cabin from a kitset last year and during the summer one of the planks arced a bit. How can I pull both planks together so I can nail a bracer to close the gap?

[image: Wall planking showing a gap]

[image: Full wall planking showing a gap]

Comment: that would open a gap somewhere else

Comment: @jsotola just that one seemed to have suffered the deformation. I got more bracing strips but I believe bracing that should do the trick

Comment: A few more pictures going up to the roof might help and a little further back.

Comment: @JACK I will get a photo of the whole wall. That’s the only gap really and that bean is used for both bracing the cabin as well as a bean for some shelves I put up.

Comment: @JACK updated with full wall photo

Comment: Wood expands and contracts. That's one of its properties and there's not a whole lot you can do about it. Normally, these would have been ship-lapped or tongue and groove joints so as the wood moves, there's some from the other piece to keep the gap closed to air flow. Seems like a poorly designed kit.

Comment: @FreeMan, that _is_ beveled t&g. Click into the image and you can see it.

Comment: I'm not seeing it even fully zoomed in, @isherwood, but I'll take your word for it.

Comment: Look two joints up from the gapped one in the first photo. Hard to miss there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could possibly pull the two boards together with a short tie down strap and ratchet but you'd need to screw in a couple screws in the two boards to attach the strap. As @jsotola pointed out though, that would create another gap somewhere else. Unless you can get another straight board from the kit manufacturer or a lumber yard, your best bet would be to swap the warped board to a location that less noticeable, like behind the bed at floor level and put a bead of caulk or some quality wood filler in the crack.

Comment: That's what I had in mind. Remove the stud that is supporting the shelves, bring the boards together and apply a bracing and put the stud back again to hide the fix. I was more checking if there was a more cleaver way like the ones with hammers some fella in IG do. :)

Answer (score 3):

JACK answered your question, so I'll pontificate a bit on the problems with this "construction" strategy in general. (I quoted anonymously just there because I consider this less construction than crafting.) Some of it is merely my opinion.

- Modern pine boards are very young. They're soft, have wide grain, and are less stable than in generations past. Because of this, they move. When applied to the exterior of a building, they move too much. I'm genuinely surprised that you have just one such gap.
- Beveled tongue-and-groove boards are not really an exterior treatment. The engagement isn't adequate to retain water shedding. "Shiplap" boards have a wider lap that tolerates movement better.
- You have virtually no lateral support due to the utter lack of framing. There are no studs!  I wouldn't want to get caught in this structure in foul weather.
- Pine isn't a very durable exterior material anyway. Even if you keep it well sealed it might last 15 years before it begins to rot away in hidden places.

This may have been an inexpensive means to an end, and I hope it serves you well. Were it mine, though, I'd be making enhancements to both structure and longevity.

Comment: Excellent pontification.

Comment: I totally get your points. As it is, this cabin has gone through pretty foul wether from local storms to a tailend of a cyclone a few weeks ago and it's still going. I braced the whole cabin with studs in the corners and middle of walls but I've been replacing some so I can hang to shelves up. I use this cabin as my home office to work from home and it's been great.